# How to Get specifit character in string in php

Tags: php, mysql

i want to get a word until a spesicif character, example space. i trying to use substr but i cant.

Assumming i have column data :

```
1. 3/14/2016 13:46 

i would like to get 3/14/2016 and showing it. is that possible?



2. 3/14/2016 13:46 
i would like to get 13.46 without date. is that possible?
```

can someone tell me how to get string from 2 case above.

thanks a lot

Comment: Did you take a look at `strtotime()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the columns are space delimited then you can use an explode and pull the index of the column of which you want.

```
$rowData = "1. 3/14/2016 13:46";

$rowCols = explode(" ",$rowData);

echo $rowCols[1]; // returns 3/14/2016
echo $rowCols[2]; // returns 13:46
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$specifidCharacter = " " //Space for example
$string = "1. 3/14/2016 13:46";

$tmp = explode($specificCharacter, $string);
echo $tmp[1] //Case 1
echo $tmp[2] //Case 2
```